# Jest encountered an unexpected token for `react-bootstrap` and import css file in typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I have searched 3 days about fixing this problem in my React app, I have read a lot of similar topics and could not fix it. All the solutions are about installing `ts-jest` and  `babel`

I created my project with this command:

```
npx create-react-app sample --template cra-template-pwa-typescript
```

After editing and installing `react-bootstrap`, I have a common problem, you can see it in this image:

[image: Jest encountered an unexpected token for react-bootstrap and import CSS file in typescript]

#### The error:

```
    Details:

    /Users/shahryar/Desktop/telegram-restaurant-management-bot-ui/telegram-restaurant-management-bot-ui/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Row.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import classNames from 'classnames';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import "./OrdersComponent.css";
    > 2 | import Row from "react-bootstrap/esm/Row";
        | ^
      3 | import Col from "react-bootstrap/esm/Col";
      4 | import Button from "react-bootstrap/esm/Button";
      5 | import OrderComponent from "./OrderComponent";
```

---

I have configured `ts-jest` and `bable` like this:

#### my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "telegram-restaurant-management-bot-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-core": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-expiration": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-precaching": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-routing": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-strategies": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-streams": "^6.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "msw": "^0.48.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3"
  }
}
```

#### babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

#### jest.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

#### My test component `ClientHomePage.test.tsx`

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import ClientHomePage from './ClientHomePage';

test('should first', () => {
  render(<ClientHomePage />);
  const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /Jeagar Resto/i });
  expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

Please help me to fix it, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue also and I was frustrated by how long it took me to notice the problem.

The import you are using is the ECMAScript (esm) export of the `Row`, `Col`, and `Button`. You likely don't have your jest configured to support that (it is in experimental support anyway: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules).

You will instead likely want to use the Common JS exports (cjs).

In `ClientHomePage.tsx` you should change the imports to the following:

```
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
```

I think that should then work with jest.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the test environment to jsdom in jest configuration file.
this is a copy of my jest config

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```

in tsconfig.json file change the jsx value from preserve to react-jsx as so:

```
"jsx": "react-jsx",
```

Comment: Hi @daniel-benisti , I changed my code to your copy, when I run `npm test`it shows me the first post error image, but if I run `npx jest` I get the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'html')` error. my **test script** is `"test": "react-scripts test"`

Comment: I see, I work with a different configuration. usually in projects Jest works with react-testing-library.  the combination of both provide a lot of methods that ease the testing process. I've configured my npm test to jest i.e "test" : "jest" and installed the following packages:  "@types/jest": "^29.2.2", "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5", "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0", "jest": "^29.3.1", "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1", "ts-jest": "^29.0.3".

give it a try, i think that should work for you

Comment: I am sorry to waste your time, I tried this, but it did not fix my problem, so I upload the project in a repo if it is possible please see it: https://github.com/shahryarjb/testproject
 // the new error: `import "./ClientHomePage.css";` SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' with test: jest

Comment: I've followed the following article recommendation and it worked for me.  

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-jest-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, but thank you